# Contagem de char em C

Tags: c, char, funções

Tenho uma função em C que deve receber uma string, e ponteiros que possuem a quantidade de numeros e vogais que estão presentes na string, porém, a função não está somando cada vez que encontra um número ou uma vogal. Segue meu código:

```
int main(){
    char string[12]={"5bana22anab5"};
    bool palindromo = true;
    int qtdnumero=0,qtdvogal=0,qtdoutros=0;
    informacoes(string,&palindromo,&qtdnumero,&qtdvogal,&qtdoutros);
    if(palindromo == true){
        printf("true ");
    }else printf("false ");
    printf("numeros: %d vogais: %d outros: %d",qtdnumero,qtdvogal,qtdoutros);

}

void informacoes(char str[12], bool *palindromo, int *qtdnumero, int *qtdvogal, int *qtdoutros){
    int i, j=11,igual=1;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
       if(str[i]!=str[j]){
          igual=0;
       }
       if(str[i]=='0' || str[i]=='1' || str[i]=='2' || str[i]=='3' || str[i]=='4' || str[i]=='5' || str[i]=='6' || str[i]=='7' || str[i]=='8' || str[i]=='9')
          *qtdnumero++;
       else if(str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='i' || str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='u'){
          *qtdvogal++; 
       }
       else
          *qtdoutros++;

       if(str[j]=='0' || str[j]=='1' || str[j]=='2' || str[j]=='3' || str[j]=='4' || str[j]=='5' || str[j]=='6' || str[j]=='7' || str[j]=='8' || str[j]=='9')
          *qtdnumero++;
       else if(str[j]=='a' || str[j]=='e' || str[j]=='i' || str[j]=='o' || str[j]=='u'){
          *qtdvogal++; 
       }
       else
          *qtdoutros++;
       j--;
    }
    if (igual==0){
        *palindromo=false;
    }
}
```

O resultado da função é =  true numeros: 0 vogais: 0 outros: 0
Alguém faz ideia do porque a função não estar incrementando os contadores?

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` e substitui aqueles `if`s enormes por `if (isdigit((unsigned char)str[j])) /* ... */;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instrucao `*ponteiro++` (`*(ponteiro++)`) aumenta o ponteiro e devolve o valor existente antes do incremento.
Para aumentar o valor apontado usa `(*ponteiro)++` (o valor devolvido 'e tambem o valor apontado antes do incremento).

```
int a[2] = {42, -1};
int *ponteiro = a;
(*ponteiro)++; // a[0] += 1;
*ponteiro++;   // ponteiro aponta para a[1]; o valor da expressao e 43
43;            // expressao com valor 43, sem efeitos colaterais
11*4-1;        // outra expressao de valor 43
(*ponteiro)++; // a[1] += 1;
printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
```